# onclick setAttribute href from a src

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, href, setattribute

I'm working on a project to swap thumbnail images to a larger image when the thumbnail is selected and it's working ok however, I would now like the end users to be able to click on the larger image to show it in jquery.lightbox-0.5. The problem is that after selecting the thumbnail the loaded image does not have a href. I was hoping that I could pass the images src to the href using an onclick event, but I can't figure out how to make this work.

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swaphref(image) {

document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('href', this.src);
//window.alert(document.getElementById('image').src);
}
</script>

<body>
<div class="productimage" id="gallery"><a onclick="swaphref(this)"><img id="image" img src="product_images/<?php echo $targetID; ?>/<?php echo $targetID; ?>.jpg" width="253" height="378" border="0" /></a></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to set the "href" attribute of an "img" element? The interesting attribute is "src", not "href", unless I'm missing something about the lightbox plugin.

Comment: because the onclick is on the a, "this" will refer to the a element not the image.

Comment: Should the following work....

Comment: Should the following work.... <script type="text/javascript">
 function swaphref(image) {

  
 document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', this.href); 
 window.alert(document.getElementById('image').src);
 window.alert(document.getElementById('image').href);
 }
</script>
<body>
<a ><img src="product_images/1.jpg" name="image" width="340" height="480" id="image" /></a>
<p><a href="href.php" onclick="swaphref(this)">add href</a></p>
</body>
I get undefined on the href alter, why?

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I got this working. The 'a' was missing an id.

Here's the code.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swaphref(imagehref) {

document.getElementById('imagehref').setAttribute('href', image.src);

//window.alert(document.getElementById('image').src);
//window.alert(document.getElementById('imagehref').href);
}
</script>

<body>
<div class="productimage" id="gallery"><a href="#" id="imagehref"     onclick="swaphref(this)"><img id="image" img src="product_images/<?php echo $targetID; ?  >/<?php echo $targetID; ?>.jpg" width="253" height="378" border="0" /></a></div>

</body>
```

Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the `href` and `src` attributes. Looking at your code I see two things:

document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('href', this.src);
   //window.alert(document.getElementById('image').src);

You're setting the image's href-attribute, which should src, and your getting the src-attribute from the link, which should be href. The odd thing is that your correct in the window.alert

So:

document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', this.href');
   window.alert(document.getElementById('image').src

Should work.

Comment: Sorry I'm missing a line of commented code  //window.alert(document.getElementById('image').src);. For test purpose to see if the href is changed on the onclick. I get undefined as a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.setAttribute('href', image.src);
```

Should work.

Comment: Nope doesn't work for me. I still get an undefined if I use and alert.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('href', this.src);
```

to this way

```
document.getElementById('image').setAttribute('src', this.href);
```

Comment: I need to change the href to the src using onclick.